# Converting Pillow byte image to numpy array is very slow

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am doing instance segmentation with mark-R-Cnn, the result is a boolean 2d array. I am working on big images (2448, 3264), and I have lots of object per image. Saving the result (or just having it in memory) is huge, like 30Gb ! I don't know why 2d numpy boolean array are taking so much space (masks are also 2448x3264). So I am storing it as a byte which reduce the total memory footprint to only a few Mb. The problem I am facing is that I need to convert this back to a numpy array to be able to detect if point with X,Y coordinate is inside the mask of an object (I do this a lot in different functions), and this operation **np.asarray(im_arr)** is very slow, it is taking 6 seconds on a loop of 1000 iterations. I also tried to do the conversion with openCV like that : *mask = cv2.imdecode(n, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[:, :, 3].astype(bool)* , but this is 4 time slower than my method *array_to_jpg_image* ...

Any idea on how I can do this in a more efficient way ?

*here is an example of a 2d boolean mask : https://pastebin.pl/view/92a7d1db*

Thanks !

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io
    
def mask_image_to_array(mask):
        img_pil = Image.fromarray(np.array(mask, dtype=np.uint8))
        img_pil.putpalette([0,0,0,255,255,255])
        bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
        img_pil.save(bytes_io, format='PNG', transparency=0, optimize=0)
        bytes = bytes_io.getvalue()
        return bytes
def array_to_jpg_image(bytes):
    im_arr = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes))
    return np.asarray(im_arr)


print(justBlademask[0][0]['masks'][:,:,0].shape)
#(2448, 3264)
#justBlademask is a boolean mask , from instance segmentation

test = mask_image_to_array(justBlademask[0][0]['masks'][:,:,0])

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(1000):
    test3 = array_to_jpg_image(test)

print('Total time elapsed: %.2f seconds' % (time.time() - start_time))
#Total time elapsed: 6.49 seconds
```

Comment: I'd like to try and help but I have read the question several times and can't see what the real problem is. Can you maybe remove all the unnecessary stuff - do I need to know about a *"justBladeMask"*? Why is some code in a pastebin - can't it be in the question? Do you have a sample image? Are you saying 6ms is too slow for something?

Comment: Why are you writing a PNG to BytesIO too?